# how to set permission 777 to my document root while cloning a php repo in apache server?

Tags: php, git, apache, yii2, vps

I'm trying to clone a git repo from github in the `www` folder of my apache server.  it says

> fatal: could not create work tree dir 'myapp'.: Permission denied

I think it's a permissions issue. I can neither set `777` on `www`, nor can I clone my repo into a subdirectory e.g. `www/myapp/` because then my application will have to be accessed as such :  `www/myapp/myapp/index.html` .. What is the common best practice in such scenario?

Comment: why can't you save it within ```www```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply as root make a dir and set the owner to the user. For example, as root (or with sudo):

```
mkdir /var/www/myapp
chown -R usernameofyourusr:www-data /var/www/myapp
chmod 755 /var/www/myapp
```

then switch to user:

```
su usernameofyouruser
cd /var/www/myapp
ls -l
```

and you are ready to gitclone. Or gitinit, gitremote add orign 'urlofrepo' and finally git pull origin branchyouwant

Edit: if your application needs write permissitions then use chmod 775 instead. But you must not set 777, it is a security hole.